# How can I get the commits between the last release and the current snapshot version?

Tags: git, commit, release

I would like to get the commits between the last release and the current snapshot version without specifying the last release.

Currently I have the following command:

```
 git log 1.2.3..HEAD
```

Is there a generic reference to the last release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "last release" you mean the last tag then yes, there is a way. This command

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```

prints the last tag in the current branch. So your command becomes

```
git log `git describe --tags --abbrev=0`..
```